# AutoML Language Entity Extraction score_threshold not accepted as a parameter

Tags: python, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-automl-nl

Environment details

- OS type and version: Windows 10, WSL 2, Ubuntu 16.04
- Python version: 3.7.5
- pip version: 19.3.1
- `google-cloud-automl` version: 2.2.0

Steps to reproduce

1. Call AutoML Language Entity Extraction with score_threshold as params

Code example

```py
options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint='automl.googleapis.com')
prediction_client = automl_v1.PredictionServiceClient(client_options=options)
payload = {'text_snippet': {'content': 'sample text', 'mime_type': 'text/plain'} }
params = {"score_threshold": "0.04"}
request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
```

Stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT
        details = "List of found errors:        1.Field: params; Message: Key `score_threshold` is not supported.      "
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1615914477.923586200","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:172.217.4.74:***","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1061,"grpc_message":"List of found errors:\t1.Field: params; Message: Key `score_threshold` is not supported.\t","grpc_status":3}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "google_keyword_generation.py", line 167, in <module>
    call_nlp()
  File "google_keyword_generation.py", line 137, in call_nlp
    request = prediction_client.predict(name=model_name, payload=payload, params=params)
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/automl_v1/services/prediction_service/client.py", line 498, in predict
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/mnt/d/alexa/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 List of found errors:   1.Field: params; Message: Key `score_threshold` is not supported.
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameter `params` -> `score_threshold` is **not available for AutoML NL Entity Extraction**. This is only available for AutoML Vision Classification and AutoML Vision Object Detection. See the [python reference for predict()](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/services.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.services.prediction_service.PredictionServiceClient.predict).

> **params** (Sequence[~.prediction_service.PredictRequest.ParamsEntry]) –
>
> Additional domain-specific parameters, any string must be up to 25000
> characters long.
>
> **AutoML Vision Classification**
>
> score_threshold : (float) A value from 0.0 to 1.0. When the model
> makes predictions for an image, it will only produce results that have
> at least this confidence score. The default is 0.5.
>
> **AutoML Vision Object Detection**
>
> score_threshold : (float) When Model detects objects on the image, it
> will only produce bounding boxes which have at least this confidence
> score. Value in 0 to 1 range, default is 0.5.
>
> max_bounding_box_count : (int64) The maximum number of bounding boxes
> returned. The default is 100. The number of returned bounding boxes
> might be limited by the server.

But if you are using AutoML NL Classification, score_threshold could be set using [batch_predict()](https://googleapis.dev/python/automl/latest/automl_v1/services.html#google.cloud.automl_v1.services.prediction_service.PredictionServiceAsyncClient.batch_predict).